# Reboot right after suspend/sleep, if system is left in S3 mode for long enough

Tags: suspend, hardware, acpi

I have a ASRock B450-Pro4 motherboard (CPU is AMD Ryzen 3200G) with Ubuntu 18.04 (is technically KDE Neon, hence the main desktop is KDE) and Windows 10 Pro 1909 dual-booting, both booting with UEFI. The problems I will describe are now happening on any OS, even on Windows 10.

Sometimes I may put my system to sleep/S3 mode, often for a few hours, whenever I need to quickly resume at a later time, but wish to conserve some electricity. Here is where the problem lies: **Instead of resuming normally, my system often reboots back to the POST screen, as if I turned it on from a shutdown or full reboot.** It is a mild annoyance in that it costs some time to fully boot up again and that I lose unsaved work. Additional observations:

- I have observed this behavior whenever I had the Firefox web browser open and/or let the monitors be turned off automatically at least once per session. It has not seemed to happen if I suspend from LightDM.
- If I resume my system from S3 quickly enough (within 30 minutes), this problem does not occur at all.
- BIOS version is 3.90, the latest as of this writing. The related setting is "Suspend to RAM". I can only choose between "Disabled" (S1 mode) or "Auto" (S3 mode + maybe other things). S1 mode creates more issues such as freezing.
- I have not tested whether this problem also occurs in Windows 10 (the only officially supported OS by ASRock) or other desktop environments.
- KDE has a related setting in "Energy Saving" -> "While sleeping, hibernate after a period of inactivity", but it is not enabled. I haven't tested hibernation by itself on this motherboard, but that likely isn't the problem here.
- I have a total of 16GB DDR4/PC4-2400 RAM, consisting of 4x4GB sticks. One of them has XMP support, the other three do not. Resizing my swap space did not solve my problem. 2GB of this total is allocated for use with the integrated graphics.
- Checking in with journald shows that no kernel logs appear between the time I use S3 mode and the reboot; it might also be something to do with the BIOS settings.
- Newer kernel versions may fix my problem, but versions > 5.3.0 are not available for Ubuntu 18.04, even as HWE. This may make me wait until Ubuntu 20.04 is released to get access to them, if I only stick to LTS versions.
- On every startup, I receive messages like this:

  ```
  Mar 09 19:38:05 B450-Pro4 kernel: ACPI: Video Device [VGA1] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
  Mar 09 19:38:05 B450-Pro4 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM.AFN7], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/psargs-330)
  Mar 09 19:38:05 B450-Pro4 kernel: Initialized Local Variables for Method [_BCM]:
  Mar 09 19:38:05 B450-Pro4 kernel: Local0: 00000000f0f8d969 <Obj>           Integer 00000000000000FF
  Mar 09 19:38:05 B450-Pro4 kernel: Local1: 000000000bc3edd7 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
  Mar 09 19:38:05 B450-Pro4 kernel: Initialized Arguments for Method [_BCM]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
  Mar 09 19:38:05 B450-Pro4 kernel: Arg0:   00000000b65d91ec <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000064
  Mar 09 19:38:05 B450-Pro4 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.GP17.VGA.LCD._BCM due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-531)
  Mar 09 19:38:05 B450-Pro4 kernel: ACPI Error: Evaluating _BCM failed (20190703/video-357)
  Mar 09 19:38:05 B450-Pro4 kernel: input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:0f/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input3
  ```
- The most recent observations show that S3 mode or S1 mode is no longer working properly in any OS, not even under the supported Windows 10. I bet now that this could be a BIOS or hardware problem.

**I found out that my old power supply looked like it was aging, to the point where 5V SB seemed to not work anymore. Replacing it with another one returned things to normal. Turns out that nothing else but an aging/faulty power supply can cause suspend/sleep to not work properly.**

Comment: Is this a new issue? (was it working properly at one point and then you started having this issue recently?) Did you flash your MB BIOS or did it come with 3.90? Since this is happening with both OS's then I would check BIOS settings and play with power management settings. To be safe you should take a picture of all the BIOS screens and then choose "load factory defaults" first and put settings back to the way they were originally if factory defaults doesn't help. Loading factory defaults is always recommended after flashing MB BIOS. If this just started happening, then did you install anythi

Comment: I just tried replacing the power supply. Turns out that my old one looked like it was aging, to the point where 5V SB seemed to not work anymore. After replacing the power supply and trying to use suspend/sleep again, things returned to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my old power supply looked like it was aging, to the point where 5V SB seemed to not work anymore. Replacing it with another one returned things to normal. Turns out that nothing else but an aging/faulty power supply can cause suspend/sleep to not work properly.